# Generate week fields between 2 timestamps for each row

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to shorten my code by removing all the PHP looping bloat. I have following table structure:

```
tdata_weight
-----
INT id (PK)
VARCHAR Name
DOUBLE Weight 
TIMESTAMP StartDate
TIMESTAMP EndDate
```

I'd like to generate all possible `WEEKOFYEAR()` fields  between `StartDate` and `EndDate`, show the current year and divide `Weight` by the count of all possible `WEEKOFYEAR()`'s.

So the resulting table would look something like this:

```
tdata_weight_part
-----
VARCHAR Name
DOUBLE WeightPart
INT Year
INT Week
```

My current solution involves looping through the table in PHP, but I'd like to shorten that by doing the most work through a SQL query... if that's possible.

**Edit:**

Here's the data I have:

```
id: 1
Name: 'Machine1'
Weight: 50000
StartDate: 2015-03-01 00:00:00
EndDate: 2016-04-09 00:00:00
```

And I want to process it into this table:

```
Name: 'Machine1'
WeightPart: 862.07
Year: 2015
Week: 9

Name: 'Machine1'
WeightPart: 862.07
Year: 2015
Week: 10

Name: 'Machine1'
WeightPart: 862.07
Year: 2015
Week: 11

(...)

Name: 'Machine1'
WeightPart: 862.07
Year: 2016
Week: 14
```

I know that there's a difference of **58** `WEEKOFYEAR()`'s between `StartDate` and `EndDate`. The `StartDate` starts on **week 9** in **2015**, the `EndDate` ends on **week 14** in **2016**. The year 2015 had a total of **53** weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every thing is possible in mysql 
there is one method where we can find the differnce between dates
like

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,'2016-02-01','2016-02-29');
```

By using this query you get number of week between start date and end date

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,StartDate,EndDate);
```

**EDIT**

```
set @a = 0;
set @timeDiffence :=  TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK, '2015-03-01 00:00:00', '2016-04-09 00:00:00');
set @start_week_of_year := WEEKOFYEAR('2015-03-01');
set @start_year := YEAR('2015-03-01');
SELECT weeks, years FROM (
select @start_week_of_year AS weeks, @start_year AS years,IF(@start_week_of_year = 52, @start_year := @start_year + 1,'' ),
IF(@start_week_of_year < 52, @start_week_of_year := @start_week_of_year +1, @start_week_of_year := 1),
 if(@a < @timeDiffence,  @a := @a+1, @a := null) from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where selected_date between '2015-03-01' and '2016-04-09' and @a is not null) AS TEMP;
```

This will give you week and year between two dates 
**Output**

```
+-------+-------+
| weeks | years |
+-------+-------+
|     9 |  2015 |
|    10 |  2015 |
|    11 |  2015 |
|    12 |  2015 |
|    13 |  2015 |
|    14 |  2015 |
|    15 |  2015 |
|    16 |  2015 |
|    17 |  2015 |
|    18 |  2015 |
|    19 |  2015 |
|    20 |  2015 |
|    21 |  2015 |
|    22 |  2015 |
|    23 |  2015 |
|    24 |  2015 |
|    25 |  2015 |
|    26 |  2015 |
|    27 |  2015 |
|    28 |  2015 |
|    29 |  2015 |
|    30 |  2015 |
|    31 |  2015 |
|    32 |  2015 |
|    33 |  2015 |
|    34 |  2015 |
|    35 |  2015 |
|    36 |  2015 |
|    37 |  2015 |
|    38 |  2015 |
|    39 |  2015 |
|    40 |  2015 |
|    41 |  2015 |
|    42 |  2015 |
|    43 |  2015 |
|    44 |  2015 |
|    45 |  2015 |
|    46 |  2015 |
|    47 |  2015 |
|    48 |  2015 |
|    49 |  2015 |
|    50 |  2015 |
|    51 |  2015 |
|    52 |  2015 |
|     1 |  2016 |
|     2 |  2016 |
|     3 |  2016 |
|     4 |  2016 |
|     5 |  2016 |
|     6 |  2016 |
|     7 |  2016 |
|     8 |  2016 |
|     9 |  2016 |
|    10 |  2016 |
|    11 |  2016 |
|    12 |  2016 |
|    13 |  2016 |
|    14 |  2016 |
+-------+-------+
58 rows in set (0.09 sec)
```

Comment: I did that, but then I get the amount of weeks between the two dates, not the difference between the `WEEKOFYEAR` of `StartDate` and `EndDate`. I can do this: `WEEKOFYEAR(EndTermin) - WEEKOFYEAR(StartTermin)`, but then I am only limited to one year difference.

Comment: @HitomiTenshi can you provide some example what you want ?

Comment: @HitomiTenshi same data put with no of week ?

Comment: Yes. If I do `TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK, '2015-03-01 00:00:00', '2016-04-09 00:00:00')` the result is 57 weeks instead of 58.

Comment: @HitomiTenshi can you try this by procedure ?

Comment: Yes I can use procedures. Is this only solvable through a procedure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104271/discussion-between-vipin-jain-and-hitomitenshi).